# PHP Serialize AWK command speed up?

Tags: php, sed, awk

I've built an SQL migration script that will replace text in a MySQL dump file. Replacements would be easy with `sed`, but we must account for [special serializations (PHP Serialize)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902647/sed-match-replace-url-and-update-serialized-array-count). The code below works but the `awk` command is very expensive. With a quick google search, I see many developers with the [same runtime performance issues](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/274156-how-make-awk-command-faster.html). [This article](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/192471-making-faster-alternative-slow-awk-command.html) breaks down how simple changes can make a large difference. If anyone knows how I can speed this command up, or faster alternatives, that would be amazing :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

SQL_FILE="$1"

maindomain="$2"

localdomain="$3"

sed 's/;s:/;\ns:/g' "$SQL_FILE" | \
  awk -F'"' '/s:.+'$maindomain'/ {sub("'$maindomain'", "'$localdomain'"); n=length($2)-1; sub(/:[[:digit:]]+:/, ":" n ":")} 1' | \
  sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/ /g' | \
  sed "s/$maindomain/$localdomain/g" > "$SQL_FILE.txt"

rm "$SQL_FILE"

mv "$SQL_FILE.txt" "$SQL_FILE"
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue faced above was solved by updating the libraries behind `awk` on (MacOS 12.6 (21G115)). After running `brew install cgrep` and `brew install gawk` the `awk -F'"' '/s:.+'$maindomain'/ {sub(...` command shown in the problem statement above saw dramatic improvements. From `3-5 minutes` to ~ `sys 0m0.039s.`

I did not need to change the `awk` command to `cgrep` or `gawk`.